# System.Threading.Timer is not firing

Tags: c#, timer

In the DLL I have one class which uses `System.Threading.Timer` in order to execute a particular method at regular intervals. 
I am using this DLL in my WINFORM application, but the timer is not firing.

It is executing only once eventhough I am maintaining a reference to this Timer.

Any idea on why this Timer is not working?

Comment: Code or it didn't happen. Oh... I see your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to set the AutoReset property to true, or call Start() again each time it elapses.

Comment: i am using the following code for creating Timer.

'callbackTimer = new TimerCallback(MethodName); 

executionTImer=new System.Threading.Timer(callbackTimer, null, new TimeSpan(0), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));'

Comment: executionTImer.AutoReset = true; //set true so the timer continue

Comment: There's no AutoReset property on System.Threading.Timer. You're thinking of System.Timers.Timer.